# Calculate StartDate and EndDate for This Quarter and Last Quarter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

I need to calculate a StartDate and EndDate of a current Quarter and the previous Quarter in vb.net.

Comment: business quarters, so the first quarter of would be Jan/Feb/March

Comment: Okay, that makes solving the problem fairly straightforward; I'll post an answer below. The point of my question is that each company and each country use their own definition of "quarter."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgive my lack of a VB.net-specific answer, but given a generic sort of date object with various functions in some pseudo-language (with zero-based day and month indexes)...

```
//round the current month number down to a multiple of 3
ThisQuarterStart = DateFromYearMonthDay(Today.Year,Today.Month-(Today.Month%3),0);
//round the current month number up to a multiple of 3, then subtract 1 day
ThisQuarterEnd = DateFromYearMonthDay((Today.Month<9)?(Today.Year):(Today.Year+1),(Today.Month-(Today.Month%3)+3)%12,0) - 1;
//same as above, but minus 3 months
LastQuarterStart = DateFromYearMonthDay((Today.Month<3)?(Today.Year-1):(Today.Year),(Today.Month-(Today.Month%3)+9)%12,0)
LastQuarterEnd = ThisQuarterStart - 1;
```

**Edit converted above pseudocode to working VB.Net:** /Stefan

```
Dim ThisQuarterStart As Date = New Date(Today.Year, Today.Month - (Today.Month Mod 3) + 1, 1)  
Dim ThisQuarterEnd As Date = New Date(CInt(IIf(Today.Month < 9, Today.Year, Today.Year + 1)), (Today.Month - (Today.Month Mod 3) + 3 Mod 12) + 1, 1).AddDays(-1)
Dim LastQuarterStart As Date = New Date(CInt(IIf(Today.Month < 3, Today.Year - 1, Today.Year)), (Today.Month - (Today.Month Mod 3) + 9 Mod 12) + 1, 1)
Dim LastQuarterEnd As Date = ThisQuarterStart.AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: sweet!  I am so tired and burnt right now this was a real help.

Comment: This does not work, if today is December. It gives "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime." error.

Answer (score 11):

I know you specified `VB.Net`, but I'm far more comfortable writing uncomplied code in `C#`. I'm sure someone can translate if necessary.

```
public static DateTime QuarterEnd() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    int year = now.Year;
    DateTime[] endOfQuarters = new DateTime[] {
        new DateTime(year, 3, 31),
        new DateTime(year, 6, 30),
        new DateTime(year, 9, 30),
        new DateTime(year, 12, 31)
    };
    return endOfQuarters.Where(d => d.Subtract(now).Days >= 0).First();
}
```

I prefer this solution over others that involve modulo arithmetic and ugly conditionals in that it is fairly easily modified to handle non-standard quarter definitions. The definition of a `QuarterStart` method is handled similarly, and is left as an exercise for the dear reader . Alternatively, you can modify this method to return a `struct` containing the desired starting and ending dates.

**Edit, added VB.Net-version of above C#-code** /Stefan:

```
Public Function QuarterEnd() As Date
    Dim endOfQuarters As Date() = New Date() { _
        New Date(Now.Year, 3, 31), _
        New Date(Now.Year, 6, 30), _
        New Date(Now.Year, 9, 30), _
        New Date(Now.Year, 12, 31)}
    Return endOfQuarters.Where(Function(d) d.Subtract(Now).Days >= 0).First()
End Function
```

Comment: +1, and special thanks for "exercise for the dear reader" in `QuarterStart` implementation

Comment: LINQ Tip: you can avoid the Where and just say .First(d => d.Subtract(now).Days >= 0);

Answer (score 2):

The vb.net convertion needs a change. 
Changed it to vb 6 and it should read;

ThisQuarterStart = DateSerial(today.Year, today.Month - (IIf(today.Month Mod 3 = 0, 3, today.Month Mod 3)) + 1, 1)

ThisQuarterEnd = DateSerial(CInt(IIf(today.Month < 9, today.Year, today.Year + 1)), ((today.Month - (IIf(today.Month Mod 3 = 0, 3, today.Month Mod 3)) + 3) Mod 12) + 1, 1) - 1

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74069374/543814) is a simple way to obtain the start date of the quarter for any given `DateTime` in C#. Converting the code VB.NET should be trivial.

From there, it's mostly easy:

```cs
var startOfCurrentQuarter = GetFirstDayOfCurrentQuarter(dateTime);
var startOfNextQuarter = startOfCurrentQuarter.AddMonths(3);
var endOfCurrentQuarter = startOfNextQuarter.AddDays(-1);
var endOfNextQuarter = startOfNextQuarter.AddMonths(3).AddDays(-1);
```

Beware of the last one. It's tempting to try to get the end of *next* quarter by doing <s>`endOfCurrentQuarter.AddMonths(3)`</s>, but that is likely to land on the wrong day (September 30 => <s>December 30</s>).