# Quarter End Date

Tags: c#, datetime, modulo

What would be the easiest way for me to assign my quarter end month based upon the month im in?

Is there something i can use like modulo? I want the simplest case and least amount of lines of code

My quarter ends months are months 3,6,9 and 12.

I want to avoid doing a logic like this:

```
if (1 <= mymonth && mymonth <= 3)
    mymonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3, 15);
else if (4 <= mymonth && mymonth <= 6)
    mymonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 6, 15);
else if (7 <= mymonth && mymonth <= 9)
    mymonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 9, 15);
else
    mymonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 15);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1492079/1070452

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var quarterEndMonth = 3 * Math.Ceiling((double)currentMonth / 3);
```

[Demonstration](https://ideone.com/7Me7vn)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public DateTime GetQuarterEnd(int month)
{
    if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        throw new ArgumentException("month is not a valid Month of the year.");

    var mod = month % 3;
    var actual = month / 3 + (mod > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, actual * 3, 15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Least amount of lines could be something like this:

```
var d = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3*(1+(mymonth-1)/3), 15);
```

But that is ugly as hell :)

https://dotnetfiddle.net/HZfFLF