# VB.NET DateTime OutOfRangeException

Tags: vb.net, datetime, math

I have created a function that I feed a quarter (1, 2, 3 or 4) and a year (for example 2014).
This function then calculates the first and the last day of this quarter.

It works fine sometimes, but when I feed quarter "4", I get an argument-out-of-range-exception in this line:

```
Dim dtLastDay As New DateTime(uYear, 3 * uQuarter + 1, 1)
```

I am not sure why this happens.
Can somebody help?

Thank you very much!

```
Public Sub QuarterYearToDates(ByVal uQuarter As Integer, ByVal uYear As Integer, ByRef uStart As Date, ByRef uEnd As Date)

        Dim iMonth As Integer
        If uQuarter = 1 Then
            iMonth = 1
        ElseIf uQuarter = 2 Then
            iMonth = 4
        ElseIf uQuarter = 3 Then
            iMonth = 7
        ElseIf uQuarter = 4 Then
            iMonth = 10
        End If

        Dim dtFirstDay As New DateTime(uYear, 3 * uQuarter - 2, 1)
        Dim dtLastDay As New DateTime(uYear, 3 * uQuarter + 1, 1)
        dtLastDay = dtLastDay.AddDays(-1)

        uStart = dtFirstDay
        uEnd = dtlastday

    End Sub
```

Comment: Learn to use debugger, it could help in this and similar situations.

Comment: You may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/568122/897326

Comment: You've already worked out the initial month of the quarter with `iMonth`. Is there a reason you aren't using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass that value, it evalutes to 13, and there is no 13th month.

You could handle this instead by using:

```
uEnd = dtFirstDay.AddMonths(3).AddDays(-1)
```

The [`DateTime.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will handle this correctly for you.

Answer (score 2):

Order of operations for (3 * uQuarter + 1) is

( 3 * 4 ) + 1

or 13.  There is no month 13.

Comment: If uQuarter is 4, then `3 * (uQuarter + 1)` will evaluate to 15 which is also a bad value for month.  Perhaps the expression should be `3 * (uQuarter - 1)`

Comment: good point =/  removed my example, since @ReedCopsey has the better code.